# How to prevent attaching multiple handlers on window

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have a JS file and it is getting included twice on a website.

- Included by user
- Injected by my Chrome Extension

JS code attaches an event listener on window. This event listener is getting fired twice instead of one due to obvious reason explained above.

This code seems to be working fine but **I want to know the right approach**.

```
if (typeof customMessageEventListenerAdded == 'undefined') {
    addListener(window, 'message', handleMessage);
    customMessageEventListenerAdded = true;
}
```

I want to know how to handle this case properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually compose my scripts like this (I usually write JS to customize Dynamics CRM but the same approach should fit a "normal" webpage):

```
if (typeof (window.theScript) == 'undefined') {
    window.theScript = {
        someValue: ...;
        someFunction: function(){ ... };
        ctor: function(){ ... };
    };
    window.theScript.ctor();
}
```

Multiple inclusions make the `if` go `false` and the code is skipped (obviously `theScript` should be a unique identifier). All code is wrapped in functions and I can control what's called and when it's called and done.

Other methods are out there (i.e. one could leverage `requirejs` just to name one).

Comment: +1 Nice approach. I think I can go for it. Much better approach.  Let's wait for sometime for someone else to chime in with a better approach (if exists) otherwise I will accept